# Is it possible for different classes to detect 'emits' from eachother in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, class, node.js, events

I am struggling with what seems to be a simple concept which makes me think what I am doing can't be done.

In nodejs, if class objectA.emits('hey there'), can class objectB.on('hey there') repsond with 'yo'?

Object A and B have nothing to do with eachother other than they both extend EventEmitter and are in the same nodejs app.

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I can't find it.

Comment: How does `objectB` respond the "yo"? With another emit? or should `objectA` listen to `objectB` to receive the "yo"?

Comment: I guess the way I envision it is objectA does something, and releases an emit to the rest of the app.  I wan other instantiated objects to be able to listen for those and react by doing something.  This could also be bi-directional, as in objectA might be listening for events from the rest of the app as well.

Comment: @user1500053 That means that "the rest of the app" needs to subscribe, by hand, to `A`, using `A`s `.on` or `.addListener` methods (do the same thing). See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. That's pretty much it.

When dealing with Observer/Publisher-Subscriber patterns (or Mediator Patterns), the point is that it really doesn't matter what type of class it is that's doing the "emitting".

Assuming that `A` is an emitter:

```
var B = { doStuff : function () { console.log("Yo!"); } };

A.addListener("someEvent", B.doStuff);
A.emit("someEvent");
```

If you actually want them to talk back and forth, then you need to manually subscribe them to one another...

Assuming that both `A` AND `B` are emitters:

```
B.doStuff = function () { this.emit("B's event", "Yo!"); };
A.doThing = function (param) { console.log(param); };

B.addListener("B's event", A.doThing);
A.addListener("A's event", B.doStuff.bind(B));

A.emit("A's event");
```

Alternatively, you should look into a Mediator pattern (which also "emits", but is intended to be 1 object which mediates between many objects who don't know one another, but use the same event-names and pass well-defined data-structures, like a good API should).

Assuming that `Mediator` is an emitter, and `A`, `B` and `C` aren't:

```
var A = {
        getData : function (request) { /* network call */ this.dataCallback(data); },
        dataCallback : function (data) { Mediator.emit("data-recieved", data); }
    },
    B = {
        display  : document.getElementById("data-display"),
        showData : function (data) { /* make DOM representation */ }
    },
    C = {
        input : document.getElementById("request-input"),
        button : document.getElementById("request-button"),
        getRequest : function () {
            var request = this.input.value;
            this.requestData(request);
            this.disableButton();
        },
        requestData : function (request) { Mediator.emit("data-request", request); },
        disableButton : function () { this.button.disabled = true; },
        enableButton  : function () { this.button.disabled = false; }
    };


    Mediator.addListener("data-request", A.getData.bind(A));
    Mediator.addListener("data-received", B.showData.bind(B));
    Mediator.addListener("data-received", C.enableButton.bind(C));

    C.button.addEventListener("click", C.getRequest.bind(C), false);
```

So now you've got 3 classes who know nothing about one another, each has its own special purpose, and the only expectations that they have of "one another" are that event-names and data-types are appropriate.

They ***all*** know about `Mediator`.
If you want Mediator to be further abstracted, then you can pass a reference to it when you're making your class:

```
function A (param1, param2) {
    var emitter = null;
    this.setEmitter = function (myEmitter) { emitter = myEmitter; };
    this.emit = function (evt, data) {
        if (!emitter) { return; }
        emitter.emit(evt, data);
    };
    this.subscribe = function (evt, callback) {
        if (!emitter) { return; }
        emitter.addListener(evt, callback);
    };
    /* rest of the object */
};


var a = new A();
var b = new A();


a.setEmitter(Mediator);
a.subscribe("some-evt", a.doSomething.bind(a));

b.setEmitter(Mediator);
b.subscribe("other-evt", b.doSomethingElse.bind(b));

a.emit("other-evt", { /* data */ });
```

`a` and `b` don't have to be the same class, here, at all.
And now they ***DO*** work in the way that you're imagining.
Both have used Dependency Injection ("Inversion of Control") to point to the same emitter (`Moderator`), so they're both working off of the same event-list, without even knowing it, and using their own methods to subscribe to `Moderator`s events.